# Upload PDF or DOC file with wordpress media with subscriber give me a error

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

i have use BuddyPress Docs. when i have try to upload a image from my front end website. it will be uploaded successfully with subscriber. but when i have try to upload .PDF of .xlsx file it will give me a error

> Sorry, this file type is not allowed for safety reasons.

But when i will change role of user to Administrator than `.PDF` and `.xlsx` file will also uploeded. 
so how can i give permission to media for all file type to all user role.
i have also add below in my `/wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php`

```
add_filter('upload_mimes','add_custom_mime_types');
function add_custom_mime_types($mimes) {
    return array_merge($mimes,array (
            'pdf'                          => 'application/pdf',
            'doc'                          => 'application/msword',
            'pot|pps|ppt'                  => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
            'wri'                          => 'application/vnd.ms-write',
            'xla|xls|xlt|xlw'              => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            'mdb'                          => 'application/vnd.ms-access',
            'mpp'                          => 'application/vnd.ms-project',
            'docx'                         => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
            'docm'                         => 'application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12',
            'dotx'                         => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template',
            'dotm'                         => 'application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12',
            'xlsx'                         => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
            'xlsm'                         => 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12',
            'xlsb'                         => 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12',
            'xltx'                         => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template',
            'xltm'                         => 'application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12',
            'xlam'                         => 'application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12',
            'pptx'                         => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
            'pptm'                         => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12',
            'ppsx'                         => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow',
            'ppsm'                         => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12',
            'potx'                         => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template',
            'potm'                         => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12',
            'ppam'                         => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12',
            'sldx'                         => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide',
            'sldm'                         => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12',
            'onetoc|onetoc2|onetmp|onepkg' => 'application/onenote',
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn’t allow us to upload all kinds of files in media library, even for the zip files you get error.

**Method 1:**

*Filter hook*

The correct function is below (place this code in your `function.php` file), if you want to allow other file types you just need to add them in `$exisiting_mimes` array:

```
<?php
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'add_custom_upload_mimes');
if (!function_exists('add_custom_upload_mimes')) {
 function add_custom_upload_mimes( $existing_mimes ){
  $existing_mimes['zip']  = 'application/zip';
  $existing_mimes['swf']  = 'application/x-shockwave-flash';
  $existing_mimes['rtf']  = 'text/richtext';
  $existing_mimes['tiff'] = 'image/tiff';
  $existing_mimes['pdf']  = 'application/pdf';
  $existing_mimes['doc']  = 'application/msword';
  return $existing_mimes;
 }
}
?>
```

There is other way also, which disables file type upload limit. For some people, the first method is OK but for others, who are constantly uploading different types of files on their blog, this is not a good solution.

**Method 2:**

*Disabling The Filtering*

This process of disallowing certain types of files in WordPress is known as filtering. You can simply disable this filtering by using following code. You have to add it in your `wp-config.php`.
`define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);`

**Note:** Now you have allowed upload for all types of file on your blog. This may lead to serious security issues. Take care that any file uploaded on the server can be executed if it is not managed properly.

Comment: Yes i have done it with youe method 2. but also add some other things.
i have added below Code in to my **"wp-content/themes/my-theme/function.php"**
`global $wp_roles;
define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$role = $current_user->roles;
$wp_roles->add_cap( $role[0], 'unfiltered_upload' );`

Comment: If my answer helped you, then mark it, so other users can benefit from this information in future.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Just Replace with this code
> ```

[More Info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_mimes)

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes=array() ) {
    $existing_mimes['pdf']                          = 'application/pdf';
    $existing_mimes['doc']                          = 'application/msword';
    $existing_mimes['pot|pps|ppt']                  = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
    $existing_mimes['wri']                          = 'application/vnd.ms-write';
    $existing_mimes['xla|xls|xlt|xlw']              = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    $existing_mimes['mdb']                          = 'application/vnd.ms-access';
    $existing_mimes['mpp']                          = 'application/vnd.ms-project';
    $existing_mimes['docx']                         = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
    $existing_mimes['docm']                         = 'application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12';
    $existing_mimes['dotx']                         = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template';
    $existing_mimes['dotm']                         = 'application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12';
    $existing_mimes['xlsx']                         = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
    $existing_mimes['xlsm']                         = 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12';
    $existing_mimes['xlsb']                         = 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12';
    $existing_mimes['xltx']                         = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template';
    $existing_mimes['xltm']                         = 'application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12';
    $existing_mimes['xlam']                         = 'application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12';
    $existing_mimes['pptx']                         = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation';
    $existing_mimes['pptm']                         = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12';
    $existing_mimes['ppsx']                         = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow';
    $existing_mimes['ppsm']                         = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12';
    $existing_mimes['potx']                         = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template';
    $existing_mimes['potm']                         = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12';
    $existing_mimes['ppam']                         = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12';
    $existing_mimes['sldx']                         = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide';
    $existing_mimes['sldm']                         = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12';
    $existing_mimes['onetoc|onetoc2|onetmp|onepkg'] = 'application/onenote';
    return $existing_mimes;
}
```